# Facebook Graph API - Is there is a way to determine if a user has uploaded a photo?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Some FB users have not uploaded a profile photo. When they authenticate to my app I don't want to store these default FB photos like so:

```
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v1/yp/r/yDnr5YfbJCH.gif
```

Is there an API call I can use to determine if the user has uploaded a custom photo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No.

Don't know what else to tell you :)

The only way I could think of doing it would be to pull the user's `albums` and look for the "Profile Pictures" album. There's a `count` element there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/
Your app can subscribe to changes to a user's properties. The profile picture is a property of the user object so you can be notified when it changes. The other photos are not properties of the user object, they are listed under Connections at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ so I don't know if you can access them from the real time notification api. Whatever, you need the user_photos permission to list them.